# VLOOKUP multiple results

Tags: excel

I'm currently stuck with getting several VLOOKUP results. I've tried the formula below:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Tblgnip3[CONDITION / STATUS], SMALL(IF(Tblgnip3[E.M NUMBER]=$I$10, ROW(Tblgnip3[E.M NUMBER])-ROW($I$10)+1), ROW('ASSET HISTORY TRACKER'!I7:'ASSET HISTORY TRACKER'!I7))),"")
```

However, it gives me a different result from the different cell.

Here's my current build:

2 Sheets:
The Sheet where I gather the result is called "ASSET HISTORY TRACKER"
The Sheet where the result is displayed is called "ITEM TRACKER"

Table:
tblgnip3 is the table where I am getting the data.

Columns are:
E.M NUMBER, ITEM CODE,  ITEM TYPE,  MAKE/MODEL W/ SERIAL NUMBER,    DEPARTMENT, PURCHASED DATE, PURCHASED PRICE,    CONDITION / STATUS, PREVIOUS CDP,   CURRENT CDP,    PREVIOUS STAFF, CURRENT STAFF,  DATE UPDATED / TRANSFERRED, UPDATED BY, LOCATION,   and WARRANTY

ITEM TRACKER SHEET:
The cell I10 is my lookup value.

Can someone put me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: *Can someone put me in the right direction* - Very hard to lend a hand when it's not clear what your desired result is. Can you post an example (even with dummy data) of an expected result?

Comment: @ScottHoltzman Right sorry for that. Here's an example:

Comment: @ScottHoltzman

Here is my [Sheet 1](https://postimg.org/image/5184j7k8j/), This is where my main table is for example.

Here is my [Sheet 2](https://postimg.org/image/b0vvmv50z/), And this is the result that I'm trying to achieve.

However, the code above is not working, that's why I'm asking for help.

Hope this helps clear things. If you need anything else, please let me know.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You should use Pivot Table.
For exam:
[image]

Comment: Pivot is ok but, I would very much appreciate it if someone can help me with the code.


I understand this part of my code:

    =IFERROR(INDEX(Tblgnip3[CONDITION / STATUS], SMALL(IF(Tblgnip3[E.M NUMBER]=$I$10,

However, this line, I have no idea:

    ROW(Tblgnip3[E.M NUMBER])-ROW($I$10)+1), ROW('ASSET HISTORY TRACKER'!I7:'ASSET HISTORY TRACKER'!I7))),"")